# Forloop with new_values

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have been playing around with a dataset about football, and need to group my ['position'] by values, and assign them to a new variable.

First, here is my dataframe

```
df = player_stats[['id','player','date','team_name','fixture_name','position','shots', 'shots_on_target', 'xg', 
               'xa', 'attacking_pen_area_touches', 'penalty_area_entry_passes', 
               'carries_total_distance', 'total_distance_passed', 'aerial_sucess_perc', 
               'passes_attempted', 'passes_completed', 'short_pass_accuracy_perc', 'medium_pass_accuracy_perc', 
               'long_pass_accuracy_perc', 'final_third_entry_passes', 'carries_total_distance', 'ball_recoveries', 
               'total_distance_passed', 'dribbles_completed', 'dribbles_attempted', 'touches', 
               'tackles_won', 'tackles_attempted']]
```

I have split my ['position'] as it had multiple string-values, and added them to a column called ['position_new].

```
position_new
AM    277
CB    938
CM    534
DF      7
DM    604
FW    766
GK    389
LB    296
LM    149
LW    284
MF      5
RB    300
RM    160
RW    323
WB    275
```

What I need, is basically to have 3 different variables who have all the same columns, but are separated by the value in the position_new. Look at the below scheme:

[image]

So: my variable: Att, need to have all the columns of df, but only with values in position_new that are equal too: FW, LF, RW.

I know how to hardcode it, but cannot get my head around, how to transform it into a for loop.

Here is my loop..

```
for col in df[29:30]:
  if df.loc[df['position_new'] == 'FW', 'LW', 'RW']:
      att = df
  elif df.loc[df['position_new'] == 'AM', 'CM', 'DM', 'LM', 'RM']:
      mid = df
  else:
      defender = df
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do but it looks like you want to get all positions that are of type attackers, midfielders, and defenders based on their two-letter abbreviation into separate variables.

What you are doing is not optimal because it won't work on any generic data frame with this type of info.

But, if you want to do it for just this case, you are simply missing the correct comparison operator in your for loop. Try:

`if df.loc[df['position_new'].isin(['FW', 'LW', 'RW'])]:`

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. I simply dropped the forloop and used the isin and it works perfectly. So thank you for that! Can I ask if you would give create the forloop if it should be optimal ?

Comment: Didn't understand the question in your last sentence. Can you please rephrase?

Comment: Sorry: "Can I ask you how you would create a for loop on any generic data frame". I am referencing to your sentence:  "What you are doing is not optimal because it won't work on any generic data frame with this type of info."

Comment: By using constant values like `df[29:30]`, this will only work on your particular dataframe structure. It looks like you are working on some data that is within the 30th-31st rows of the data frame. This comment only makes sense if you are trying to build something that can generalise across many such datasets.